# JetBrains, Setting up window for the first time doesn't work

Tags: c++17, window, game-development, clion, jetbrains-ide

I wanted to create my first small game so I followed along a video for setting up a window. The video was on VSCode but I use JetBrains so I had some issues switching my subsystem, change configs and platform. I don't know where the issue could be. Following I'll send my `CMake.lists.txt` and the source file named `win32_platform.cpp`:

**Cmake:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)

project(newjourney)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(newjourney WIN32 main.cpp
        win32_platform.cpp)
if (WIN32)
    add_compile_options(-Wl,--subsystem,windows)
endif()
```

**Source file:**

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

    bool running = true;

LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    LRESULT result = 0;
       switch (uMsg) {
           case WM_CLOSE:
           case WM_DESTROY: {
                running = false;
           } break;

           default: {
               result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
                    }
           }
           return result;
}

int  WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd){

    // Create Window Class
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = "Game Window Class";
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;
    // Register Class
    RegisterClass(&window_class);
    // Create Window
    HWND window = CreateWindowA(window_class.lpszClassName, "Findus!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    while(running){
        //Input
        MSG message;
        while(PeekMessage(&message, window, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }
        //Simulate

        //Render
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

I wanted to open up a window, for instance if it might help here is the video I followed along https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD0WzbKJcOg